# Is there ERC721 decimals?

Tags: erc-721, nft

Is it possible to have decimals balances in ERC721 ?

I mean is it possible to say i own 50% of an NFT for example ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to several formal implementations, `ERC721` is not supposed to a divisible token by itself.

Although, you can deploy an `ERC721` through an `ERC20` and distribute its `shares` using the fungible `ERC20` tokens.(not my idea, check below link)

Watch this for full explanation: [DeFi + NFT Tutorial | Code a Re-Fungible Token (Solidity + Tests)](https://youtu.be/9CBDj5A-zz4)

Comment: This is strange because ERC1155 has decimals in metadata files...

Comment: You can ask the developers who have made those contracts.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [`ERC1155` contracts](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/1155) designed by Enjin, they provide a way to set up fractional ownership an asset in a single contract.
OpenZeppelin [implementation here](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/token/erc1155)

That being said, `ERC721` can allow for `decimals` as stated in its [EIP here](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721):
"An implementation may also include a function decimals that returns uint8(0) if its goal is to be more compatible with ERC-20 while supporting this standard."