# What should I write in token decimal while importing NFT in Metamask

Tags: metamask, nft

When I tried to import NFT to my Metamask wallet, I found out that "Token Decimal" input should be filled.
I know NFT doesn't have decimal so does it mean I should fill it with 0?

[image: Token Decimal input in Metamask]

Comment: what does etherscan report?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

NFTs have a decimals value of `0`.

Conceptually you cannot split a simple non-fungible token in half (think of sending half a painting to a buyer). Only natural values.

Technically, we can read in the ERC-721 that the standard requires the `0` decimals (amounts will only be integers `>= 0`):

> An implementation may also include a function decimals that returns uint8(0) if its goal is to be more compatible with ERC-20 while supporting this standard.

---

For technical reference, see an earlier answer [here](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/97072/is-there-erc721-decimals/97081) (includes another standard as well)